# What is the unit of the coordinate system in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks

If I use the following code, there two different kinds of units. One for the coordinate system used to declare `\begin{pspicture}` with (0,0) to (20,10), and the centimeter used in 4.2cm.

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,10)
\rput[lt](0.5,9){\psframebox[linewidth=1pt,framearc=0]{\parbox[c]{4.2cm}{\raggedright Text Goes Here...}}}
\end{pspicture}
```

Can I use a unified dimension for both PSTricks objects and `\parbox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pstricks` manual says on page 6:

> The values of the `runit`, `xunit` and `yunit` parameters are stored in the dimension
>   registers `\psunit` (also `\psrunit`), `\psxunit` and `\psyunit`.

So you should be able to use:

```
\parbox[c]{4.2\psxunit}{...}
```

to get the width of `4.2` in the `pstricks` coordinate system. However, if you using complex transformations this might not work correctly, I guess. You can set the units using `\psset{xunit=1cm}` etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `parbox` is a TeX macro and arguments follow the TeX rules for units. Values without a unit are not possible without rewriting the macro. In PSTricks you can mix all kinds of units; `\psline(3,4in)(5cm,2)` The current default unit is set by `\psset{unit=...}`, preset to 1cm. And you can you `\psTextFrame` instead of `\rput`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,10)
\psTextFrame[linewidth=1pt](0.5,8.5)(4.7,9){\parbox[c]{4\psunit}{Text Goes Here...}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the unit of measure for the parameters specified with `\begin{pspicture}(lx,ly)(ux,uy)`? It is obvious that this does not - should not - change whenever you reset units using `\psset{unit=...}` and the like.

Comment: I do not understand what you really mean. There is no difference in using the coordinates for lines or for the environment pspicture. Any unit is possible and it is _internally_ converted to pt

Comment: So, when specifying `\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,10)` it internally converted to be equivalent to `\begin{pspicture}(0pt,0pt)(20pt,10pt)`?

Comment: no, the default unit is cm, so it is converted to `(0pt,0pt)(57.64pt,28.82pt)`

Comment: That answers my question completely. Thanks! I din't know what the default unit was for the environment coordinates, since I did not notice it in the [PStricks documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).